# fatal error: No such file or directory when I'm sure I have set find_package correctly

Tags: c++, cmake, aruco

I am trying to compile my own scripts that use aruco (v 3.0.7) on Linux. I am using a makefile but when I compile I get this error.

```
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/aruco_simple.dir/aruco_simple.cpp.o
/home/ucfaptv/opt/aruco-3.0.7/mine/aruco_simple.cpp:2:25: fatal error: aruco/aruco.h: No such file or directory
 #include <aruco/aruco.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/aruco_simple.dir/aruco_simple.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/aruco_simple.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8) 
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED PATHS "/home/ucfaptv/opt/opencv-3.4.4/build")
find_package(aruco REQUIRED PATH "/home/ucfaptv/opt/aruco-3.0.7/src")

add_library(aruco_simple SHARED aruco_simple.cpp)
target_link_libraries(aruco_simple aruco ${OpenCV_LIBS})

add_executable(run run.cpp)
target_link_libraries(run aruco_simple aruco ${OpenCV_LIBS})

add_executable(view view.cpp)
target_link_libraries(view aruco_simple aruco ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

I thought `find_package` should point to the `aruco.h` located in `/home/ucfaptv/opt/aruco-3.0.7/src`

Using the same makefile (paths edited) I can compile just fine on my Mac.

---

I have now install aruco! A colleague pointed out that as I am installing locally (e.g. not `make install`) `aruco.h` in not in the directory `/usr/local/include/aruco` so the include statement is now `#include <aruco.h>`. I also had to edit the `aruco.pc` and `arucoConfig.cmake` files to point at the `/home/ucfaptv/opt/aruco-3.0.7/src` directory and not at `/usr/local/include`

Comment: This is a cmake issue; it's not related to make.  You should have a cmake tag and not a makefile tag.

Comment: Did you install opencv from source? If so, you should add opencv_extra path in cmake. You don't have to show where is aruco. Only opencv should be enough in your case. Check your opencv installation. If you installed aruco from source, cmake and make should handle the path related problems. So I believe you don't need to give the path. Can you check and update ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your package, you still need to add the include path to add it to the compilation commands:

```
include_directories(${aruco_DIR})
```

(variable set according to https://github.com/elliotwoods/ArUco-MarkerMapper/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt)

And same for OpenCV.

Comment: Thanks @Matthieu but that didn't solve it, can I test if aruco set the usual variables?

Comment: Just updated by answer after looking up some aruco examples.